# Convert data collection into nested hierarchical object list

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm wanting to make an API call that gets all the unique survey IDs and put them into an array with total answer counts based on the unique answer value and list of user ids. For example: `ICollection<Survey>`

```
ID Survey_Id       Answer  User
1  Apple_Survey    1       Jones
2  Apple_Survey    1       Smith
3  Banana_Survey   2       Smith
4  Apple_Survey    3       Jane
5  Banana_Survey   2       John
```

The API result I currently have:

```
{Data: [
  {
      survey_id: "Apple_Survey",
      answer: "1",
      user: "Jones"
  },
  ...
]}
```

Where I get stuck is in the code to process the data:

```
foreach (var info in data
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Survey_Id)
                     .Select(group => new { SurveyId = group.Key, 
                                          Count = group.Count() }) )
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", info.SurveyId, info.Count); 
    //Result: Apple_Survey 3 Banana_Survey 2
}
```

Ideal results:

```
{Data: [
  {
      survey_id: "Apple_Survey",
      answers: [//Example: rating answer would be 1-10, not an ID
             {answer: "1", count: 2, users: ["Jones", "Smith"]},
             {answer: "3", count: 1, users: ["Jane"]}
      ]
   },
   ...
]}
```

How can I get the distinct answers based on survey_id and the list of users based on the answer? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your results json doesn't look like valid json. Instead of `answers: [1:{count: 2, users: [Jones, Smith]}, 3:{count: 1, users: [Jane]}]` maybe it would be better to add a property for the answer Id such as `answers: [{answerId: 1, count: 2, users: [Jones, Smith]}, {answerId: 3, count: 1, users: [Jane]}]`?

Comment: @RuiJarimba you're right! i'll edit it

Comment: your example also does not look like valid JSON @RuiJarimba because string data needs to be double qouted in JSON to be valid.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you're absolutely right, it should be `answers: [{answerId: 1, count: 2, users: ["Jones", "Smith"]}, {answerId: 3, count: 1, users: ["Jane"]}]`?

Comment: double qoutes not single quotes thats isn't valid JSON @RuiJarimba besides keys also needs to be double quoted if those are string data.

Comment: Oooops I think it's time to go home.... One more try: [{"answerId": 1, "count": 2, "users": ["Jones", "Smith"]}, {"answerId": 3, "count": 1, "users": ["Jane"]}]

Comment: i wonder if using LINQ is the answer for this case here.. MySQL can generate valid JSON data with JSON functions  like JSON_OBJECT and JSON_ARRAY https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html out off the box otherwise you can simulate those with CONCAT AND GROUP_CONCAT on MySQL version lower then 5.5/5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if following helps :

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Survey> surveys = new List<Survey>() {
                new Survey() { ID = 1, Survey_Id = "Apple_Survey", Answer = 1,  User = "Jones"},
                new Survey() { ID = 2, Survey_Id = "Apple_Survey", Answer = 1,  User = "Smith"},
                new Survey() { ID = 3, Survey_Id = "Banana_Survey", Answer = 2,  User = "Smith"},
                new Survey() { ID = 4, Survey_Id = "Apple_Survey", Answer = 3,  User = "Jane"},
                new Survey() { ID = 5, Survey_Id = "Banana_Survey", Answer = 2,  User = "John"}
            };

            var results = surveys.GroupBy(x => x.Survey_Id).Select(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.Answer)
                .Select(y => new { answer = y.Key, count = y.Count(), users = y.Select(z => z.User).ToList()}).ToList())
                .ToList();
        }

    }
    public class Survey
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Survey_Id { get; set; }
        public int Answer { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This does not tell which user gave which answer.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for that.  Not sure if it is needed.

Comment: It's in his `Ideal results` section... Jones and Smith say Apple 2, Jane says Apple 3. `list of users based on the answer` can only mean `list of users for each answer`.

Comment: Yep, that's basically the same as my linq statement, with the order of a select and a groupby reversed :-)

Comment: @jdweng I was able to get the result that I was looking for from your previous answer. I just wanted to add that you can combine GroupBy of survey id and answer instead of doing 2 separate GroupBy. I'll update the answer later and give credit to this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Kendra Chu : Your grouping and mine would give different nesting in the results.  My results looks like your ideal answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is based on sql only.. you could use a query as :

```
select Survey_Id, Answer, COUNT(*)  answer_count, group_concat(user) answer_user
from my_table  
group  Survey_Id, Answer
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for

```
table.GroupBy( x => x.Survey_Id ).Select( x => new { Survey_Id=x.Key, Answers=x.GroupBy( y => y.Answer ).Select( y => new { Answer=y.Key, Count=y.Count(), Users=y.Select( z => z.User)})} )
```

That creates an ienumerable of pairs of a survey and an ienumerable of answers, each with its count and an ienumerable of the users that voted for that answer.

Try it out on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AnJuHq)!